# rpy2 glmnet getting coefficients with row names

Tags: rpy2, glmnet

I am using `glmnet` in Python using rpy2. However, I am not sure how to return the row names of the matrix in Python. Following only returns the matrix but not the variable names.

```
model = glm.cv_glmnet(x=XW_1, y=Y_1, **{'penalty.factor': penalty_factor})
coefs = np.array(base.as_matrix(glm.coef_glmnet(model, s="lambda.min")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `.rownames` ?

```
base.as_matrix(glm.coef_glmnet(model, s="lambda.min").rownames
```

(see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#rpy2.robjects.vectors.Matrix.rownames)

Comment: Yeah, this only gives the V1, V2, V3 ... , but not really the real variable names. I am actually now just creating my own function to extract the names. Thanks.